# MySQL Full Text Search and Joins

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, full-text-search

I have built a celebrity photo website. After reaching 100,000 photos, my amateur skills have started to show up and need honing, quickly. Some simple queries are taking 5-10 seconds to return!

I have a one text-box search feature, which will search the "photos" table (for caption and headline), the "people" table, the "keywords" table and the "photoContributor" table. There are two relational/association tables for "people" and "keywords" called "photoPeople" and "photoKeyword".

One possible user search maybe:
"Brad Pitt Angelina Jolie Sunglasses @MG" - This should return all photos that contain Brad and Angelina together, where Sunglasses can be seen and taken by the contributor @MG.

I soon realised that I could not use an INDEX on my "caption" and "headline" fields in the "photos" table because I am using the "LIKE" clause with a "%" prefix, and that those particular fields are set to a "LONGTEXT" data type. Because I have no indexes on those fields, it's causing huge return times. Therefore, I believe I need to use "FULLTEXT" search, I can then set the "caption" and "headline" fields to VARCHAR(2000), as the largest caption to-date is 1991 characters, and still use the "INDEX" feature, which will hopefully speed things up. I also like the boolean function to remove words from the search too.

The reason I am writing this question, is that I am totally useless at "JOINS". I can probably write a "FULLTEXT" query on one table and I can probably join two tables together using a left or right join... but because I have the association/relational tables in between, I get really, really confused.

I would appreciate if somebody could please show me an example query, using joins and full-text and using relational tables, or just explain to me which joins to use, if any, and any tips you have for full-text on the database structure I have.

Below is my basic database schema:

```
photos (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)         Primary     Auto-Increment
headline            Long-Text
caption             Long-Text
dateCreated         DateTime

people (tbl)
peopleID            INT(11)         Primary     Auto-Increment
people              VarChar(255)

photoPeople (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)
peopleID            INT(11)

keywords (tbl)
keywordID           INT(11)         Primary     Auto-Increment
keyword             VarChar(255)

photoKeyword (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)
keywordID           INT(11)

photoContributor (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)
contributorRef      VarChar(100)
```

When a search is made, the tables/fields that are queried are:
photos.headline, photos.caption, keywords.keyword, people.people, photoContributor.contributorRef.

I hope somebody can help me on my way to build this *urgent* query.

Comment: fulltext indexes only work on MyISAM tables. They've never been (and the way things are going, probably never will be) supported on InnoDB.

Comment: My table is using MyISAM engine, does this help my cause..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having both full text searches and foreign key contraints (which are good for joins) is a hassle for MySQL as they are only supported by MyISAM and InnoDB engines respectively.

In order to make full text searches you would have to have tables to the MyIsam engine. I dont have that much experience there so i cant help you much.

The time sink as you guessed, is that you are using like with a %prefix, forcing the database to look at every damn entry in the table before returning.

If you want to use joins, you will have to split up the query string before polling the database, but that should be fairly easy.
A good introduction to joins can be found in the W3school tutorials.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

The main problem i can see you running into is this:
Even if you manage to get some decent joins implemented in your database, you will still need to use like on the joined tables (Because you cant do full text searches on InnoDB). Because of this making fancy joins will not speed up your queries much.

My advise would be this:
Make more search fields. Doing so will make it possible to get something good out of joins.
Split the persons name up into First, middle last name to avoid needing to use Like.

If you really want to keep the one textfield search, you might need to put down some conventions about how to enter data (So you can split it up behind the scenes and search) like you are doing with a prefix for contributor.

Im sorry that i cant be more precise and helpful than this, but what you are presenting is not a quick-fix problem, im afraid.

Comment: Thanks for a speedy response. I agree this is issue will take time to complete.

Comment: I have just checked and my tables are using the MyISAM engine.I already have an advanced search page where users can use multiple text-boxes but everybody seems to use the quick search box, which doesn't run very well at the moment, hence needing a new query.

Comment: And also, it is just my caption and headline fields that use "LIKE". The keywords, people and contributor fields all have to be exact matches e.g. WHERE keyword = 'Sunglasses'

Comment: I am guessing that the photos table is one of, if not the largest table in your database. If so, using two "like" queries is devastating. I will almost guarantee that that is what is killing your search times. Like with a % prefix checks the entire string from left to right for your match, meaning crazy search times. Multiply that by 2 and multiply it again by the number of rows in the table, and you got yourself hell. If make those 2 "like" into full text searches, i am almost certain that you wont need to worry about joins at all...